# How to solve eslint react-hooks plugin warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using eslint react plugin and I got an following warning.
`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setEmail'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`.

Here is the code snippet that occurs warrning.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const email= localStorage.getItem('email');
    if (email) {
      setEmail(email);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is `setEmail` defined by a `useState` hook?

Comment: No. `const setEmail = email => setFormState({ ...formState,  email });`. `setFormState` is defined by a `useState` hook.